# Ability to exclude specific paths in Applinks(Deeplink)

Tags: android, applinks, android-deep-link, android-app-links

**Statement** :
Exclude certain urls paths from Applinks

Let's say our application is configured with applinks to handle the domain `http://www.example.com/` and I wish to exclude `http://www.example.com/redirects` path.

Following methods we had checked for

1. `assetlinks.json` doesn't support excluding/including a path like Apple's apple-app-site-association file.
2. In `intent-filter`, we can include a path but we cannot exclude a path
3. Negative overlook regex is not supported in `intent-filter` paths

http://www.example.com/ (open app)

http://www.example.com/redirects (don't open app)

http://www.example.com/dashboard (open app)

Is there any other way achieve this ?